# Object extensions in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to have object extensions in JavaScript? For example

Extensions.js

```
function any.isNullOrEmpty() {
  if (this == null || this == "") {
     return true
  }
  return false
}
```

app.js

```
var x = ""
console.log(x.isNullOrEmpty()) //should log true
```

is this possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method to the [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) prototype, and use the [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method to get the value of the string:

...but, because [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) is a primitive that cannot have a method, the only way I can think of to get the target to be `null` would be to use `call`, `apply` or `bind`.

But you would never do this in production code, because modifying the prototype of built-in objects is discouraged.

```js
'use strict' // important for the use of `call` and `null`

Object.prototype.isNullOrEmpty = function() {  return this === null || this.valueOf() === '' }

const s = ''
console.log(s.isNullOrEmpty())

const t = null
console.log(Object.prototype.isNullOrEmpty.call(t))
```

Comment: There is a [proposal for a this-binding syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) which, if adopted, would allow to easier use a free method to be used against a given object. For example if `isNullOrEmpty` is defined as a normal function, you'd be able to call it as `variable::isNullOrEmpty()` which will be similar to `isNullOrEmpty.call(variable)`

Comment: oh, thanks, is there a way to put it in a different file and then just import it to other files?

Comment: If this is production code, I would simply expose the method as a utility and use it as `isNullOrEmptyString(o)`. Node has built-in modularisation capability. https://adrianmejia.com/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond/

Comment: Also: you might not need this function, because there are a number of techniques for dealing with falsey values, such as using the `||` boolean operator or the ternary operator (although these will usually match `undefined` too).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.prototype` to extend this type of functionality in JavaScript.

```js
Object.prototype.isNullOrEmpty = function() {
  if (this == null || this == "") {
     return true
  }
  return false
}

var x = "";

x.isNullOrEmpty(); // returns true
```

Comment: This works, but the check for `null` in the code is useless, as `null.isNullOrEmpty()` won't work.

Comment: I'm demonstrating how to extend Object functionality using Prototype. I've used the code the op has provided :)

Comment: Also note, that using property access on primitives causes boxing. `Object.prototype.isEmpty = function() { return this === ""; }; console.log(("").isEmpty());` may have unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

---

you need to add your custom method into prop type of object or array or everything u want to use your method on it.

but in your case you need to this like code below:

```
Object.prototype.isNullOrEmpty = function(){
  if (this === null || this == "") {
       return true
  }
  return false
}
 let a = {a:'10'}

console.log(a.isNullOrEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateValue(value){

    function isNullEmpty(){
          return (value === void (0) || value == null)
    }
    return { isNullOrEmpty }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @hardcode, the author's question was more towards how to extend functionality on the string itself, for that one has to extend it on the `prototype` chain, as shown in another answers here